# How to get the total?

Tags: c

Good day, I am practicing about Arithmetic and started to experiment a bit and got confused. How can I total the liter, refueled, and tendered?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int liter, refueled, tendered, changed;
  
    printf("Enter the price of the fuel per liter: ");
    scanf("%f",&liter);
  
    printf("Enter the number of liters the customer wants refueled: ");
    scanf("%f",&refueled);
  
    printf("Enter the amount tendered: ");
    scanf("%f",&tendered);
  
  
    printf("your change is %.2f pesos. Thank you and come again!",  changed = liter * refueled - tendered);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the input supposed to be? You have declared the variables as `int` but then scan for `%f` which is for `float`. One of those need to change to match the other. Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: What do you mean with "total the liter, refueled, and tendered"?  Total usually refer to  a sum, but the `changed` calculation shows `liter` and `refueled` to be  a product, right?

Comment: A good compiler will be able to issue warnings about that code. If it doesn't you need to enable more warnings (add the option `-Wall` when building with GCC or Clang, and `/W4` when building with MSVC), and treat all warnings as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: On a minor note, you don't need the `changed` variable, as you can print the result of the calculations directly without any assignments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It seems like `float` is more appropriate for all your variables (`liter, refueled, tendered, changed`). There's no reason to allow only `integer` amounts of fuel etc. You also `scanf`ed them using **"%f"** which is used for `float`s.
2. It's better to assign `changed` in a separate line, or alternatively get rid of it altogether and simply put the mathematical expression in the `printf` call.
3. You inverted the value of `changed`. Should be `tendered - liter * refueled`.

Better version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int error_handler(/*error params*/)
{
    int errCode{ 1 };
    // Error handling based on the params, set errCode ...
    return errCode;
}

float get_change(float liter, float refueled, float tendered)
{
    return tendered - liter * refueled;
}

int main()
{
    float liter{ 0 }, refueled{ 0 }, tendered{ 0 };
    printf("Enter the price of the fuel per liter: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &liter) != 1) {
        return error_handler(/*error params*/);
    }
    printf("Enter the number of liters the customer wants refueled: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &refueled) != 1) {
        return error_handler(/*error params*/);
    }
    printf("Enter the amount tendered: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &tendered) != 1) {
        return error_handler(/*error params*/);
    }
    printf("your change is %.2f pesos. Thank you and come again!\n", get_change(liter, refueled, tendered));
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**
Following the comments below I updated my solution with:

1. Skeleton for error handling for `scanf`.
2. A separate function for the change calculation. In this case it seems a bit contrived, but it's correct from a methodical software engineering point of view (imagine this calculation getting a lot more complex in some real life scenario). **Note:** you can further apply this principle and extract for example the code for getting input from the user to a separate function. In my code above I decided it is enough to demonstrate it with `get_change` and `error_handler`.

Comment: this is the best answer for his question. A perfect solution would be to extract the calculation and put it into a function.

Answer (score 1):

Your scanning attempts, e.g. `scanf("%f",&liter);` uses the format specifier for `float`, but gives the address of an integer.
That causes undefined behaviour, which means "do not do this" for practicals (otherwise look up the term, or for fun "nasal demons").

The simplest fix (assuming you input integer values) is to switch to `"%d"`.

If you instead switch to using `float` for the variable (probably necessary), you should know, for the cases of currency (e.g. `tendered`), that a very recommended best practice is to then convert to an integer variable which counts the smallest denomination, e.g. cents.

Answer (score 1):

I took the answer of wohlstad, which was nearly perfect and added a function for your calculation...

```
#include <stdio.h>

fload calculation(fload tendered, fload liter, fload refueled);

int main()
{
    float liter, refueled, tendered, changed;
    printf("Enter the price of the fuel per liter: ");
    scanf("%f", &liter);
    printf("Enter the number of liters the customer wants refueled: ");
    scanf("%f", &refueled);
    printf("Enter the amount tendered: ");
    scanf("%f", &tendered);

    changed = calculation(tendered, liter, refueled);
    
    printf("your change is %.2f pesos. Thank you and come again!", changed);
    return 0;

}


fload calculation(fload tendered, fload liter, fload refueled){
    fload calcVal = tendered - liter * refueled;

    return calcVal;
}
```

Now you can edit your calculation like you need it, adding more or less things etc...